# How to populate updated time in other text box based on time entered in one text box using java script or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need your help here again.
I don't have any code snippet for this.

Below is my problem description:
There are two text boxes .
In one text box user will enter any time in 24 hour format say 23:23 or 10:12..

Now I need to populate time in the second text box based on this entered time.
Second text box should display value after adding the 6 hours in 24 hours format to the entered time.i.e. should display 05:23 or 16:12 and so on.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#new_one').on('change',function (e) {
        var first_time = $(this).val();
        var arr = first_time.split(':');
        var hrs = arr[0];

        var new_hrs = parseInt(hrs)+6;
        if(new_hrs>24)
        new_hrs = new_hrs-24;

        if(new_hrs < 10) 
        new_hrs  = '0'+new_hrs;

        var second_time = new_hrs+':'+arr[1];


        $('#new_two').val(second_time);

});
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Text1<input type="text" id="new_one"><br/>
Text2<input type="text" id="new_two">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The best place for you to start on figuring this out is by checking out the documentation on the JavaScript `Date` object:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date  That should help you out a lot in learning how to build out this functionality.

Comment: To help you along, the `.getHours()` method for the `Date` object returns the hour value in the 24-hour format.

Comment: Hi..Thanks a lot..I will go through the references for understanding the concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working fiddle : **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/68LQD/11/)**

```
 $('#one').on('change',function (e) {
        var first_time = $(this).val();
        var arr = first_time.split(':');
        var hrs = arr[0];

        var new_hrs = parseInt(hrs)+6;
        if(new_hrs>24)
        new_hrs = new_hrs-24;

        if(new_hrs < 10) 
        new_hrs  = '0'+new_hrs;

        var second_time = new_hrs+':'+arr[1];


        $('#two').val(second_time);

});
```

It is pretty basic just split the input string of first box on `':'` using `.split(':')` and increment hours accordingly and put the computed value to second box

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot....For me it is not adding the minute part i.e. it is coming as 16:     for 10:00 means :minute is not coming in the second text box

Comment: Sorry..my mistake....Can we make it 'onchange' ..because user might not press Key...Thanks again

Comment: Hi Need one help..When I am trying to use this code independently I am unable to implement it..Could you please help.

Comment: It's not getting posted..let me try some way to post how I am trying to do it

Comment: I have edited the question..posted the code..could you please have a look

Comment: Is that code independently working for you?..might be some issue with my browser then...

Comment: Ya sure..but could you please tell how to do that..because I am not getting any option for the same :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("#firstTime").keypress(function(){
        var firsttime = $(this).val();
        var gettime = $.trim(firsttime).split(":");
        var updatetime = parseInt(gettime [0])+6;
        if(updatetime > 24)
        {
           updatetime = updatetime-24;
        }
        if(updatetime < 10) 
         {
          updatetime  = "0"+updatetime;
         }
        $("#secondtime").val(updatetime+":"+gettime [1]);
       });
   });
```

Where your HTML will be:

```
  <input type="text" id="firsttime"><!-- first time -->
  <input type="text" id="secondtime"><!-- second time -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) to simplify the calculation as listed below. Here's an example in [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrrodd/a6CHf/).  Note, there's no validation checks and number of hours to add is hard-coded at 6.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Time Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
Start Time: <input id="startTime" type="text" /><br />
End Time: <input id="endTime" type="text" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/date.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function () {
        $("#startTime").change(function () {
           var endTime = Date.parse(this.value).add(6).hours();
           $("#endTime").val(endTime.toString("H:mm"));
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```